# Python binary tree serializing problem

Tags: python, serialization, tree

I have a binary tree class as below:

```
class BTree:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.data
```

and I have another tree serializing method listed as below:

```
class JTree(object):
    def __init__(self, id, children=None): 
        self.id = id 
        if children is None:
            children=[]
        self.children = children

def encode_tree(obj):
    if not isinstance(obj, JTree):
        raise TypeError("%r is not JSON serializable" % (o,))

    return obj.__dict__
```

then I populate the Binary Tree data as below:

```
bt = BTree("1")
bt.left =BTree("2")
bt.right=BTree("3")
```

so if I serialize the data, I can get the following result:

```
tree = JTree(bt.data, [JTree(bt.left.data), JTree(bt.right.data)])

print json.dumps(tree, default=encode_tree)


{"id": "1", "children": [{"id": "2", "children": []}, {"id": "3", "children": []}]}
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to program a piece of code to generate the result. Which means I want to have a generator or recursive function to run the code:

```
JTree(bt.data, [JTree(bt.left.data), JTree(bt.right.data)])
```

Can somebody give me an idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you want a simple recursive function like:

```
def convert_to_jtree(bt):
    return JTree(bt.data, [convert_to_jtree(bt.left) if bt.left else None,
                          convert_to_jtree(bt.right) if bt.right else None])
```

or something very similar.

Comment: This very cool! Thanks for solving my problem! A minor fix there is: convert_to_jtree(bt.left)

Answer (score 0):

The `json` module can only serialize dicts, lists, strings, numbers, booleans and `None`.  Instead of using custom classes for this, consider using plain-ol `dict`s.  Alternately, you can subclass `json.JsonEncoder` and override the `default` method so that it returns one of those types for your custom class.

Comment: Actually it does. I just added json.dumps minute ago. Still, my question is, is there any way to run a code like this: JTree(bt.data, [JTree(bt.left.data), JTree(bt.right.data)])